# Multiple GET routes with different parameters

Tags: angularjs, node.js, routes

does anyone know if u can and if its good practice to define multiple GET routes such as:

- GET: '/channels' returns all channels in the app
- GET: '/channels/:username' returns all channels created by a user
- GET: '/channels/:channelname' return details about a channel
- POST: '/channels' creates a new channel
- PUT: '/channels/:channelname' edits a channel with the name ':channelname'

What im confused is the third GET route. Don't know if it's possible or if theres a better way to do it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have multiple routes with the same parameter.
I think that the most logical way is to do this :

- GET: '/channels/user/:username' returns all channels created by a user

Comment: but the parameter is different.. one is ':channelname' and the other is ':username'

Comment: In your example yes but imagine if you have a user called "John" and a channel called "John" too. You will call the route : /channels/John and you can't handle that.

Comment: hmm, you're right.. unless u check all users before creating a new channel which would be kinda costly lol.. alright then will create another route as u said. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You couldn't use same verb (`get, post, put ..`) for same  route. You can use same `verb` for different `route` or same `route` for different `verb`.

in your problem used

```
GET: '/channels/:username'  and 
GET: '/channels/:channelname'
```

both act as a same thing because when you request by `/channels/somename` fro client site then valid for both routes because `username` can be `somename` or `channelname` can be `somename`.

so to differentiate two routes need to change your any one route. like

```
GET: '/channels/user/:username' // that different from /channels/:channelname
```

for `node.js` and `express` you can use like:

```
var router = express.Router();

router.route('/place')
        .get(placeController.getPlaces)
        .post(placeController.createPlace);

router.route('/place/:placeId') // same route for different verb
        .get(placeController.getPlaceById)
        .put(placeController.updatePlaceById)
        .delete(placeController.deletePlaceById);

router.route('/hotel/:placeId') // here :placeId params name same for both but /hotel differentiate from /place
            .get(hotelController.getHotelById)
            .put(hotelController.updateHotelById)
            .delete(hotelController.deletHotelById);
```